# Filling a listview from an online database

Tags: android, listview

Im new to programming and i have been trying to make this work for quite sometime but i havent been able to solve it, so, i want to transfer data(For now just names) from my online database to a listview and display it. I have already checked my php file and it works fine(It gives back the names i want), also  the code seems to works fine until i reach the Baseadapter part.

**Activity VerPostsUsuario**

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.github.snowdream.android.widget.SmartImageView;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONArray; 
import org.json.JSONException;   
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class VerPostsUsuario extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_posts_usuario);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    descargarImagen();


}

private ListView listView;

ArrayList nombreAnimal = new ArrayList();

private void descargarImagen(){
    nombreAnimal.clear();

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(VerPostsUsuario.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando Datos");
    progressDialog.show();

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("mydomain+php", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if(statusCode==200){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));
                    for (int i=0; 1<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        nombreAnimal.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombreAnimal"));

                    }
                    listView.setAdapter(new ImagenAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });

}

private class ImagenAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    TextView tvnombreAnimal;


    public ImagenAdapter(Context applicationContext) {
        this.ctx=applicationContext;
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewGroup viewGroup =(ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_items, null);
       tvnombreAnimal = (TextView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvnombreAnimal1);

        tvnombreAnimal.setText(nombreAnimal.get(i).toString());







        return viewGroup;
    }
```

**Activity VerPostsUsuario XML (ListView)**

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="492dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

**Activity_main_items XML**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnombreAnimal1"
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="24dp"

         />
```

Originally the tutorial also showed how to display images (Thats why there is an import "SmartImageView" and "Rect") so i deleted this part and tried to only do it with a text. Maybe i messed up somewhere but i cant find where, so if you could help me out in this one i would be very grateful.

**Edit**:

So i want to say thanks to all of the people who tried to help me out, it seems the Array had a few problems as did the Baseadapter. I will list them below for anyone who has a similar problem.

**-Array:**

Had a "1" instead of an "i" and had to replace

I was trying to get a field from the db called "nombreAnimal" when in reality in my php file i had assigned "nombreAnimal" to "Nombre" (nombreAnimal.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Nombre"));)

I also found out that the best way to check if your Array has the Values you want(Or at least something) is to Check the Logcat of Android

**-BaseAdapter:**

I forgot to get the Size from my Array in the **getCount** (Array.size;)

I forgot in the **getItem** i needed to return the "position", "i" in my case, from my array "nombreAnimal" (Array.get(i);)

I forgot in the **getItemdId** to return "i" (i;)

Comment: Please note that there is a small error in `for (int i=0; 1<jsonArray.length();i++){`, should be `i<jsonArray.length()`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks you, i didnt notice, it doesnt work but its a step into the right direction into solving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the array and how you handle the server response. This is how I made it work.

Seems like you are trying to get the value "nombreAnimal" instead of "Nombre". Try this:

```
try {
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));
     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
          nombreAnimal.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Nombre"));
     }
     listView.setAdapter(new ImagenAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Example of list working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufVk1.png)

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Yes! Now in the logs the values appear but it shows this error. Value [{"Nombre":"Carlos"},{"Nombre":"Juan"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject.  
Idk what the "result" field would be in my case

Comment: Looking at other of your comments, I notice that you are trying to get the value "nombreAnimal", and I think you should put "Nombre". I will update my answer above so you can see how the code should be.

Comment: Thanks Man!!! It finally worked, you were right it was the field i put in the php file not from my database(The tutorial explained that in that field i should put the name of my db field). So thats why it didnt work! you helped me out a lot dude im very Thankful!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that everything is correct except the implementation of the Adapter.

You are not overriding those methods properly, i let you the code to fix it.

**Code in ImagenAdapter :**

```
//You need  to return the size of the array, if you always are returning 0 the adapter dont
        //print any because they "think" the array is empty.
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return nombreAnimal.size();
        }

        //This method helps you to return the Item at specific index
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return nombreAnimal.get(i);
        }
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: It still doesnt seem to work, do you think that with this the base adapter part should work correctly ?

Comment: Could ContraintLayout on the activity main items have something to do with it? In the tutorial a LinearLayout was used

Comment: You have to add this in the ImagenAdapter for sure. But maybe you have something else wrong in your code or xml layouts.

Comment: Ok, I will check my code again for errors and i will try to find out if the array even has something on it. 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Review your `BaseAdapter` as below; you can find more information [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView)

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return nombreAnimal.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return nombreAnimal.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // inflate the layout for each list row
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_items, null);
    }

    TextView tvnombreAnimal = (TextView) 
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvnombreAnimal1);
    tvnombreAnimal.setText(nombreAnimal.get(i).toString());

    // returns the view for the current row
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work either, idk if the array might be the problem, how could i put the names into a normal textview to check if the data is there ?

Comment: can you print this line to be sure getting json data `jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombreAnimal")`
@ArchersTH177

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but by that you mean displaying it on a textview or something where you can see the data?

Comment: Yes just print it in the debug console, use Log.v or System.out

Comment: So i used a string to store that line, then used log with tag:"TAG" and id:"id"+(The string i created)
Then i started the debugger and searched for tag
and it says this twice
ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Comment: The final line of the debugger console is in red and it says  "sendUserActionEvent() mView == null"  could it be an error?

Comment: add this line
`System.out.println("COMES DATA " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombreAnimal"));`

before `nombreAnimal.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombreAnimal"));`

Comment: I cant find the system.out.print but i found this in the log "System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for nombreAnimal" " at org.json.JSONObject.get" and "at org.json.JSONObject.getString".
Should i post the php file too see if theres some kind of error there ?

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for advising me to check in the logcat, thats how i found out that my array had a problem

Answer (score 0):

try that code:

```
public class VerPostsUsuario extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_posts_usuario);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    descargarImagen();


}

private ListView listView;

ArrayList nombreAnimal = new ArrayList();

private void descargarImagen(){
    nombreAnimal.clear();

final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(VerPostsUsuario.this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando Datos");
progressDialog.show();

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("mydomain+php", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        if(statusCode==200){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));
                for (int i=0; 1<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    nombreAnimal.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombreAnimal"));

                }
                listView.setAdapter(new ImagenAdapter(getApplicationContext(), nombreAnimal));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

    }
});

}

private class ImagenAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    TextView tvnombreAnimal;
    ArrayList list;
public ImagenAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList list) {
    this.ctx=applicationContext;
    this.list = list;
    layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewGroup viewGroup =(ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_items, null);
   tvnombreAnimal = (TextView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvnombreAnimal1);

    tvnombreAnimal.setText(list.get(i).toString());







    return viewGroup;
}
```

I just added extra arraylist in your inner class.

Comment: Tried but nothing happened, there seem to be no errores on the code but for whatever reason it doesnt work. 
Do you know how to put the Array nombreAnimal data into a normal textview to check if there is actually any data on it ?